# prettify output of query

Tags: sql, oracle, layout

i have this query and would like to indent the output and get the total from the last column.
Now it gives

```
person                                          |year|dossiers
------------------------------------------------|----|--------
9210124                                         |1110|     166
9210124                                         |1111|     198
9210124                                         |1112|     162
9210161                                         |1110|     183
9210161                                         |1111|     210
9210161                                         |1112|     142
```

And i would like to have

```
person                                          |year|dossiers
------------------------------------------------|----|--------
9210124                                         |1110|     166
                                                |1111|     198
                                                |1112|     162
9210161                                         |1110|     183
                                                |1111|     210
                                                |1112|     142
total                                                     1061
```

Here the query

```
select  
 pers_nr "person",   
 to_char(import_dt,'YYMM') "year and month",  
 count(pers_nr) "dossiers"   
from   
  rdms_3codon  
where  
 trunc(import_dt) >= trunc(trunc(sysdate, 'Q') -1, 'Q') 
 and trunc(import_dt) < trunc(sysdate, 'Q')-1/(24*60*60) 
group by   
 pers_nr,   
 to_char(import_dt,'YYMM')   
order by  
 pers_nr
```

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: Data presentation should not be part of query result. Just make the layout in your programming language!

Comment: Calculating (sub)totals, pivoting tables, hiding values, are all tasks that your reporting tool can easily handle. You could calculate totals and by using UNION ALL merge them into your result set, but reporting tools are made to make these tasks a breeze, don't do them in SQL.

Comment: I  usually don't use the db engine to format data or to style the layout. In SQL Server the "COMPUTE" clause let you add an aggregate function at the bottom of a query: maybe there is such a clause in Oralce too. A quick way to format data could be using a spreadshhet to create a readable report. Regarding your data, I would use a pivot table with "person" as row header, year as column header, dossiers as data.

Comment: thanks for the comments but i have a web app that has reports that are just sql stored in a db, is very handy to quickly provide reports, the output is pumped in a grid, since all kinds of reports are used i would like to give some rudimentary output to some reports

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is a client function, not a database one. For example, if you are using SQL*Plus, you can use:

```
break on person
break on report
compute sum label total of dossiers on report
```

The first line suppresses the duplicate person values; the second and third together generate the total at the bottom. SQL*Plus output formatting etc. is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#i1081534).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It will give you the  totals at least but the rest 
either can be replaced with NULLs also using RANK() for pers_id
or in the code of your application if any...

```
select  
 pers_nr "person",   
 to_char(import_dt,'YYMM') "year and month",  
 SUM(count(pers_nr)) OVER (ORDER BY year)
FROM ....
```

hope it helps abit